Parameter domain for $y = \lceil kx+m\rceil$
Given $n$ observations of the positive integer pair $\{x_i,y_i\}$, and the non-decreasing relationship $y_i = \lceil kx_i+m\rceil$, how do we analytically, or numerically, find the joint domain for $k$ and $m$?
Naive attempt:
Naturally, the ceiling function is equivalent to
$$y_i-1 \leq kx_i+m \leq y_i.$$
Naively using the first and last observations to derive the possible minimum and maximum slope, we get that
$$\frac{(y_n-1)-y_1}{x_n-x_1}< k < \frac{y_n-(y_1-1)}{x_n-x_1}.$$
From here we can derive bounds crude bounds for $m$.
